# Using CPAN with a proxy failing after o conf init /proxy/

Tags: perl, configuration, proxy, cpan

I have a Linux box in a corporate environment in which web access is gated through a proxy which requires authentication.

During a first run of cpan it auto configures  everything that it normally does:

> Autoconfigured everything but 'urllist'.
>   Please call 'o conf init urllist' to configure your CPAN server(s) now!
>
> commit: wrote '/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/CPAN/Config.pm'

Knowing that I have a proxy to navigate, and having read the docs and several pages on the web about proxy and cpan I:

> cpan[1]> o conf init /proxy/
>
> If you're accessing the net via proxies, you can specify them in the
>   CPAN configuration or via environment variables. The variable in the
>   $CPAN::Config takes precedence.
>
> Your ftp_proxy? []
>
> Your http_proxy? [] 10.12.8.9:3128
>
> Your no_proxy? []
>
> If your proxy is an authenticating proxy, you can store your username
>   permanently. If you do not want that, just press RETURN. You will then
>   be asked for your username in every future session.
>
> Your proxy user id? [] my_net_id
>
> Your password for the authenticating proxy can also be stored
>   permanently on disk. If this violates your security policy, just press
>   RETURN. You will then be asked for the password in every future
>   session.
>
> CPAN: Term::ReadKey loaded ok (v2.30) 
>   Your proxy password? 
>   Please remember to call 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!
>
> cpan[2]> o conf commit
>   commit: wrote '/usr/lib/perl5/5.10.0/CPAN/Config.pm'

All should be good now, right?
So I wish,

> cpan[3]> i /Some::Module/
>   CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.18)
>
> I would like to connect to one of the following sites to get
>   'authors/01mailrc.txt.gz':
>
> http://www.perl.org/CPAN/  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/
>
> Is it OK to try to connect to the Internet? [yes]   LWP not available
>
> Trying with "/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional" to get
>       http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 407
>
> System call "/usr/bin/curl -L -f -s -S --netrc-optional
>   "http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz"  >
>   /root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.tmp29726"
>       returned status 22 (wstat 5632) Warning: expected file [/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp29726] doesn't exist
>
> Trying with "/usr/bin/wget -O
>   /root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.tmp29726" to get
>       http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
>   --2012-07-17 15:57:38--  http://www.perl.org/CPAN/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz Connecting to
>   10.12.8.9:3128... connected. Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently Location:
>   http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz [following]
>   --2012-07-17 15:57:38--  http://www.cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz Connecting to 10.12.8.9:3128... connected. Proxy request sent,
>   awaiting response... 407 Proxy Authentication Required
>   2012-07-17 15:57:38 ERROR 407: Proxy Authentication Required.

So where's the password prompt?

What am I missing to configure cpan to access the internet through the corporate proxy with authentication?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install LWP. The cpan utility is using curl, I guess because it couldn't load LWP. No proxy parameters are being passed to curl, so you need the export http_proxy=http://host:port/ before running the command.

Or, if you can install LWP using your distribution's package manager, then it should configure the proxy access correctly.

Comment: We have a winner.  Although it seems like putting the cart before the horse it is possible to install LWP and its 18 dependencies by hand and then cpan will navigate through the proxy.   @Luciano has it.

Comment: As an alternative to installing 19 packages from CPAN by hand, try `o conf` setting all three of `http_proxy`, `proxy_user`, and `proxy_pass` to the empty string (or removing them from `~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm` with a text editor). Then make sure `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, and the lower-case variants are set and `export`ed in your shell environment. _This worked for me with a brand new Perl installation from source and a corporate HTTP proxy that requires authentication._

Answer (score 25):

you need to provide absolute proxy URL address for configure CPAN proxy settings . don't worry instead of providing simply IP address and port number please provide as given below.

```
cpan> o conf init /proxy/

Your ftp_proxy? [] ftp://10.12.8.9:3128

Your http_proxy? [] http://10.12.8.9:3128

Your no_proxy? []
```

and provide **username** and **password** if needed (Make sure that you have the downloading permission )

I also have same the issue, but now its working for me. I should also work for you.

BR
Jerry James

Comment: This was the correct answer for me to remove the proxy.

Existing docker image/container had an env of http_proxy and I wanted to unset it.

Answer (score 5):

You can try using this before calling `cpan`:

```
export http_proxy=http://my_net_id:my_net_pwd@10.12.8.9:3128/
```

This way maybe `curl` will use the proxy.

Comment: Indeed, the input `10.12.8.9:3128` looks wrong. It should rather say `http://10.12.8.9:3128`.

Comment: @daxim  Note from the logs I posted cpan is connecting to the proxy server, it's just not doing the required authentication

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@localhost ~] cpan
```

Terminal does not support AddHistory.

cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9800)
Enter 'h' for help.

## list my download url

```
cpan[1]> o conf urllist 


urllist
    0 [http://mirror.waia.asn.au/pub/cpan/]
    1 [ftp://mirrors.coopvgg.com.ar/CPAN/]
    2 [http://httpupdate3.cpanel.net/CPAN/]
```

Type 'o conf' to view all configuration items

## add CPAN mirror list

```
cpan[2]> o conf urllist push http://httpupdate3.cpanel.net/CPAN/
```

Please use 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!

## commit

```
cpan[3]> o conf commit
```

commit: wrote '/root/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm'

cpan[4]>

now you can install perl module again like :  `cpan -i Text::Template`