# Proxy must be specified as absolute URI; '192.168.3.10' is not at /usr/share/perl/5.26/CPAN/FTP.pm line 355

Tags: linux, perl

I have been trying to install Regulatory Sequence Analysis Tools (RSAT) on my stand alone computer. The OS is Ubuntu latest version. I am new to it too. While downloading some necessary PERL modules I get this error:

**"Proxy must be specified as absolute URI; '192.168.3.10' is not at /usr/share/perl/5.26/CPAN/FTP.pm line 355.
makefiles/install_rsat.mk:256: recipe for target 'perl_modules_install' failed
make: *** [perl_modules_install] Error 255**"

Tried solving it with "perl -MCPAN -eshell" but same error pops out. Please help me .

Your help will be very appreciated

Comment: It's a web proxy, it requires you to provide a URL. Try `http://192.168.3.10`, possibly with a port.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649791/cpan-first-launch-proxy-configuration

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your CPAN proxy is misconfigured. It should be an absolute URL (as the error message says) not just an IP address. `http://192.168.3.10/` will probably work (but you might need to add a port number too).

Do you have any suggestions that would make the error message clearer?

Comment: Couldn't "Proxy" indicate a misconfigured env var?

Comment: Oh, course. I didn't say where the misconfiguration was as I didn't have enough information to even guess.

Comment: Can you tell me what more information do I need to provide ? And how do I provide it as an url ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue. Solved it by removing all configured proxies from CPAN and then using environment proxy.

You can remove configured proxies from cpan using following commands either on `cpan` or `perl -MCPAN -e shell` -

```
o conf http_proxy ""
o conf ftp_proxy ""
o conf proxy_user ""
o conf proxy_pass ""
o conf commit
q
```

And then configure required environment proxy. Example - `export http_proxy=http://proxyserver:8080` for Linux or `set http_proxy=http://proxyserver:8080` for Windows

Now you should be able to install required modules `cpan[6]> install LWP`

Comment: -bash: conf: command not found

Comment: @ChamindaBandara - looks like you are in bash and not in CPAN's shell. Try commands `cpan` or `perl -MCPAN -e shell` to connect to CPAN's shell. Run the `conf` command after connecting to CPAN shell.